# Find the licence type of a video using YouTube data API v3

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to program a JavaScript code that could detect the license of a video by entring it's ID in a var. Thus I looked at the officail page for youtube API and I came up with this url

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=gwLej8heN5c&part=status&key= { My  API Key }

which will return this result

```html
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "creativeCommon",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
```

And that is good for me scince I get "license: creativeCommon" However I can't bring that into JavaScript function.
Note: I tried to iframe it however it doesn't show any thing in the iframe even after adding &output=embed to the code.

To make this clear here is what I'm planning to do with it:

```js
var result = // somehow to get the result from the API

function licensetype() { 

var cheack = result.search("creativeCommon");

if ( cheack = -1 ) {

document.write("This video is not a creative Common");
} else {

document.write (" This video is a creativeCommon" );
```

So is there a way that I can get the result shown above in javascript variable ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Share some code how you are calling the API please?

Comment: This is my problem I'm trying to find a way to call the API and I included a sample code of what I'm planning to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you might want to try:

```
var check = result.license;

switch (check) {
    case undefined:
        // Property 'license' not in result
        break;
    case "creativeCommon":
        // Found
        break;
    default:
        // 'license' property exists but is not 'creativeCommon'
        break;
}
```

Not exactly familiar with the Youtube API, but I assume that the result returned from the query can be parsed as a JSON object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly, My issue is getting the youtube API to give me the result.license value :(

Comment: So you would like to know how to make the API call in Javascript?

Comment: yes! sir and make it return the API result in the var check shown above

Comment: You'll probably need to make the API call via an AJAX request. You can then be able to handle the result from there.

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't think of using AJAXs in the first place :)